# Are there plans to release Esperanto courses for other languages on Duolingo?

Tags: learning

I know that the Spanish language course is/will be available, but what about the other major languages?

Comment: Not really a question anybody outside Duolingo can answer.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. I believe Duolingo courses are developed by bilingual speakers not the app developers. For example, if someone spoke both German and Esperanto they could, in theory, develop a duolingo course. I simply wanted to know if anyone knew of such plans.

Comment: As far as I am aware it needs to be signed off by the company, though. Duolingo is a commercial company, and they have criteria for accepting new courses. I do know that there are plans for a German course, but Duolingo is not yet happy to set one up.

Comment: There are several different ways that this question can be answered (as reflected in the answers), but I don't think it's inherently too broad.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: I'm also for reopening this question, for the same reasons as Nathaniel.

Answer (score 24):

I'm the lead contributor for Duolingo's Esperanto course for English speakers as well as initiating the Esperanto course for Spanish speakers, so I believe that qualifies me to answer this. Duolingo uses three criteria for deciding whether a new course should be launched:

1. How much demand is there for this course?
2. Are there enough high-quality bilingual candidates to create this course?
3. Are there any technical limitations to creating this language pair?

As for **#3**, it's already been proven that the system can handle teaching an Esperanto course. Duolingo is actually amazingly well suited for Esperanto, since it teaches by induction and given the few exceptions Esperanto has, induction works incredibly well.

As for **#1** and **#2**, this will most likely determine which order new Esperanto courses are launched on Duolingo. After many public polls, Esperanto was the most demanded language **twice**, so there was no way Duolingo could possibly ignore it any longer, so then they started sifting through the candidates to choose their team. As for Spanish, there are so many Spanish speakers learning languages on Duolingo that this course was a no-brainer.

Now, looking at the number of people learning languages on Duolingo, the next likely candidates for an Esperanto course in my opinion would be Chinese, French, German, Portuguese and Russian. I believe Russian is the best option, because there are already many Duolingo courses for Russians, plus this would diversify the Duolingo community from being concentrated only in the Americas. Plus, the Russian Esperanto community is very strong with many excellent speakers and teachers, thus ensuring the course will be of very high quality.

But, in the end, it is the Duolingo community team, which will have to decide whether it believes that another Esperanto course would be beneficial for the site. I certainly hope so!

Comment: Thanks! I was curious as to whether there would be attempts to create courses for Asian languages. In my mind, it only made sense that Esperantists would try to create as many courses as possible.  And thank you so much for your work on the Esperanto course. Without you I likely would not have found this awesome language!

Comment: Yes, but each course needs resources from Duolingo to make it happen. Considering this, I personally believe we can see one new Esperanto course per year.

Answer (score 6):

The [Duolingo Incubator](https://incubator.duolingo.com/) is where courses that are "under development" are listed.  Unless you get a quote from a Duolingo employee, the Incubator serves as the first public notification of a future course.  Duolingo only lists courses here once it has selected contributors for the course and approved development of it.

At the current time (May 2018), the only courses teaching Esperanto are Esperanto for English, for Spanish, and for Portuguese:

[image: Esperanto courses]

The "phase" of each course indicates where it lies in its development.  [Esperanto for English](https://incubator.duolingo.com/courses/eo/en/status) and [Esperanto for Spanish](https://incubator.duolingo.com/courses/eo/es/status) have graduated (phase 3), while [Esperanto for Portuguese](https://incubator.duolingo.com/courses/eo/pt/status) is expected to be released to beta (phase 2) soon.

Comment: The next one is Portuguese, Brazilian it seems

Answer (score 3):

The way this traditionally works in Duolingo is that lots of people apply to create courses but do not get any feedback until Duolingo decides the time is ripe. Normally they first approve English for speakers of X, then X for speakers of English, and then, one after another, various other combinations that involve X and languages which are either very popular in the Western world (essentially Duolingo's initial languages: English, French, Spanish, Portuguese, German) or have a special relationship with X.

Since Esperanto has almost no native speakers, they made an exception for it and we will probably have to wait quite a while for an English course for Esperanto speakers. (Normally, learning these 'reverse' courses is a good next step after finishing a language in Duolingo.)

In Duolingo forums there has been speculation that the next course after Esperanto from English will be either Esperanto from Portuguese or Esperanto from German. However, the team has said that after finishing Esperanto from Spanish they will extend Esperanto from English. This might well delay the other courses even further.

Comment: Thank you! This essentially answers what I wanted to know!

Comment: Just to clarify, separate teams work on each course, so working on one course does not delay the other course at all. In addition, when one team makes a new Esperanto sentence, that is then also available for the other Esperanto team to translate!

Comment: My impression so far was that it was always essentially the same team that created English from X, X from English and then some other related courses. Presumably the relation you describe is one of the reasons.

Comment: If there were a Spanish for Esperanto Speakers course, I would totally jump on it! But I understand the demand isn't so high.

Comment: @HansAdler, ah yes, this is the exception to the rule. A team that makes a course in one direction is the same team that makes it in the other direction. We just don't have any Duolingo courses for Esperanto speakers, so I didn't consider that relevant here.

Comment: @ChuckSmith: Somehow I was under the impression that they wouldn't approve any Esperanto from Y team before Esperanto from X is finished, but maybe I was wrong about that.

Comment: @HansAdler "Somehow I was under the impression that they wouldn't approve any Esperanto from Y team before Esperanto from X is finished." Your impression is correct. In any case, we most likely we won't look at any courses from Esperanto until we've built up enough Esperanto speakers to have enough demand (my guess is around 2020).